# Converting byte[] to array issue

Tags: c#, floating-point, marshalling, bitconverter

Please check this code

```
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(new byte[] { 0xBF, 0x04, 0x8E, 0xFF }, 0);
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
```

this yeilds a strange result.
b will be { 0xBF, 0x04, 0xCE, 0xFF }

I guess it is because the value of f is NaN.
the reason I'm asking this question is because I use Marsal to convert a stream of bytes into a struct that contains a float, the I swap endianity

The thing is when I get to the field is already messed up (like the above example)

any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Change the endianity before converting it to a float

Comment: I can't.I'm converting a byte[] to struct which it's inner structure is not known to me at that stage.

Comment: @harold if you use `BitConverter` in both directions, endianness isn't a concern - indeed, that would be the issue if the bytes were *reversed*, not if they are just mutated

Comment: that is odd - need to pop out, but I will have a look at this when I get back!

Comment: @MarcGravell it is a concern this time, because the original input (ie `{ 0xBF, 0x04, 0x8E, 0xFF }`) is the wrong way around. That makes a NaN, and then things start going south.

Comment: You already know your value is NaN, so why does it matter? Where does the value come from and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @harold the main point of the question seems to be "how can I round-trip this value that is already messed up" (the "already messed up" is a direct quote from the question)

Comment: Testing locally, there doesn't seem to *be* a way to round-trip this value "as is" while preserving the fact that it is "already messed up" - even when just bit-bashing with `unsafe` (which is what `BitConverter` does under the covers anyway), loading the value out of the buffer into a `float` causes it to be treated as a `float`, correcting the oddity of the atypical `NaN`. If it **is** endianness related, then you would have to reverse that *before* parsing.

Comment: @TheDude please clarify, is this value *supposed* to be a NaN? Or something like -0.51780695

Answer (score 2):

Since your problem appears to an endian one, I'm wondering if checking for NaN and reversing the order and setting a boolean to reverse it back if necessary, would help:

```
byte[] input = { 0xBF, 0x04, 0x8E, 0xFF };
bool reversed = false;
float f = BitConverter.ToSingle(input, 0);

if (float.IsNaN(f))
{
    reversed = true;
    f = BitConverter.ToSingle(input.Reverse().ToArray(), 0);
}

byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);

if (reversed)
    b = b.Reverse().ToArray();
```

Comment: `f == float.NaN` will always be `false`. Change it to `float.IsNaN(f)`.

Comment: @AgentFire viva le Resharper

Comment: @RoyiNamir eh no, without any tools, I just checked the code out.

Comment: @AgentFire  , well , My resharper warned me about it.

Comment: @AgentFire The best.(IMO).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
double f = BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0xBF, 0x04, 0x8E, 0xFF }, 0);
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
```

This one also does:

```
int f = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] { 0xBF, 0x04, 0x8E, 0xFF }, 0);
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
```

I believe the reason is in the single floating-point storage. The third byte (`{ 0xBF, 0x04, [0x8E to 0xBE] , 0xFF }` is being `+4`'d for some reason while converted.

The good containter for 4 bytes is `Int32` and I advise you to use it.

Comment: That double represents a completely different number and is irrelevant. This is not a decimal precision issue, because the number is already in binary format. The problem here is that the bytes result in NaN. If OP just wanted to have a container for 4 bytes, why not just use a byte[]?

Comment: @Rik at least because `byte[]` as well as any other array is a reference typed object. And the `double` is still a container as well.

Comment: This should be the selected answer, because it not only explains clearly what caused the byte in question to be altered, but it also shows two good solutions when 4-byte data chunks must be passed through BitConverter twice in opposite directions, but they cannot be guaranteed to be valid single floats. There are a number of situations in which this arises. This was very helpful to me.